# What does `⟨library⟩` mean in [defns.prog.def.spec]?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

**3.42  program-defined specialization** [[defns.prog.def.spec]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.prog.def.spec)
⟨library⟩ explicit template specialization or partial specialization that is not part of the C++ standard library and not defined by the implementation.

Comment: It looks like this names a context in which the definition applies

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. As the title says this a **program-defined specialization** that is **not** part of the C++ standard library and **not** defined by the implementation.

Comment: In earlier versions of the standard, some definitions were in the "Library Introduction" chapter. These have all been moved (so that all definitions are in one placed) and marked with "library" as that is where they are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Definition context tags (non-normative / from draft `.tex` source)

The `⟨library⟩` *definition context* tags were added when moving [[definitions] from [library]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/definitions) (C++20) into [[intro.defs]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs) (current draft). The `⟨library⟩` definition context tag in the particular change you are quoting was added when [[defns.prog.def.spec] in [definitions]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/defns.prog.def.spec) (C++20 DIS) was moved into [[intro.defs]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs) as part of [the following commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/521b52fb52bb2a4a3115f2511e7a740d83e0e123)

> #### [definitions] Integrate into [intro.defs]
>
> Partially addresses ISO/CS 016 (C++20 DIS)

particularly adding the `\defncontext{library}` tag [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/521b52fb52bb2a4a3115f2511e7a740d83e0e123#diff-9d600d0fec9e0016bbfe5f8f4f943b7b09555e53bcc3740a6acf0c33834ae990R446).

These definition context tags have been present for a long time in [intro.defs], but as library definitions did not use to reside in [intro.defs], there were simply not any definitions in there for which `⟨library⟩` would be an appropriate definition context tag.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you're saying that the `⟨library⟩` context tag should not be present in [defns.prog.def.spec]. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ayrosa I did not say that: I just said that the `⟨library⟩` tag was added as [defns.prog.def.spec] was moved from [library] to [intro.defs]. However, indeed it seems the sole reason for adding this tag was that the definition _previously resided_ within [library], as opposed to _being related to library definitions_, and indeed the latter should arguably be the true source of definition context tags. In this case, I agree that the `⟨library⟩` definition context tag for [defns.prog.def.spec]  seems misplaced. This may be the case also for other definitions. ...

Comment: ... A fix is arguably only an editorial one, so if you want to report it, you could try [posting it as an editorial issue at cplusplus / draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/wiki/How-to-submit-an-editorial-issue).